# UISearchController in-accessible

Tags: uitableview, accessibility, uisearchcontroller, voiceover

I have implemented a search screen using UISearchController and a table view. When I start searching for something, the search controller adds a view on top of the table view (although, it does nothing) and until I set the searchController.active = false, the table view is in-accessible with VoiceOver. I have tried almost everything it seems, and the only solution is to abandon UISearchController for UISearchBar. Currently, once the keyboard is shown and the search controller is active, the VoiceOver selector will go from the text field, to a bar button item, then it skips the table view and goes to the keyboard. Here is my setup of UISearchController.

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .Dark
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.text = prefilledSearch
    searchController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    searchController.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    searchController.view.isAccessibilityElement = false
    searchController.view.hidden = true
    searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
```

How can I get this fixed and continue to use UISearchController? currently, search is not usable with VoiceOver users in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because underlying `UITransitionView` sets incorrect value for `accessibilityViewIsModalSelector` which traps VO within search view, which in your case is empty.

I can only think of patching this behavior by swizzling `accessibilityViewIsModal` on private `UITransitionView`.

I described the technique in a blog post I wrote:
http://www.morphineapps.com/blog/accessibility-on-ios

Relevant gists:

https://gist.github.com/pronebird/0d3c06485de50e100d1e93bcde08c94c#file-snippet-m
https://gist.github.com/pronebird/66aa70b005ed9af8d357cdc7e940542b#file-search-controller-snippet-m

Comment: In Swift, you can do 

`func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.view.superview?.accessibilityViewIsModal = false
    }`

Comment: @Maximilian this didn't work for me at the time of posting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the accepted answer is suboptimal, even though it might be technically correct.

If you use the `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` (added in iOS 9.1) and set it to `false`, VoiceOver can access the underlying table view.

Usage:

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found on this page, http://www.iaccessibility.net/report/uisearching-for-accessibility-nil, the problem is that you set searchResultsController to nil which makes the original view controller display the search results. When the search controller has focus it blocks VoiceOver from accessing the search results in the original view controller. By specifying a separate results view controller, VoiceOver will work.